# How to use TryUpdateModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am readying [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application). I see from this tutorial that for update the author is using the following code:

```
....
var studentToUpdate = db.Students.Find(id);
if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
   new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
{
    try
    {
        db.Entry(studentToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
   ...
}
```

But I don't understand why the following line is needed:

```
db.Entry(studentToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

When I remove this line, the code still works well and update is done perfectly.
Can someone help me with whether that line is needed? If so, why when I remove it, the update works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well because you find the `studentToUpdate` from your context, that's way the entity is attached and the changes that are made by the `TryUpdateModel` method  are saved when you call the `SaveChanges` method.

If you were working with a detached entity, for example doing this:

```
var studentToUpdate=new Student(){Id=id};
if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
   new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
{
    try
    {
        db.Entry(studentToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
...
}
```

In this case you have to call the `Entry` method to attach the entity to your context and change its state.

Comment: Thanks, but what's your advice? Is it better to keep that line or remove it for this specific example? I personally prefer to remove it because it's confusing (at least for me). But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: well, if you find the entity from you context, you don't need  to call the `Entry` method to change the state of the entity, unless you've disabled the change tracking

Answer (score 0):

That line is explicitly telling the EF context that the entity has been modified and needs to be updated the next time `SaveChanges()` is called.  The reason everything still works when you remove that line is that the context usually tracks those changes automatically for you.  I have yet to come across a situation where I have needed to fiddle with EF's automatic change tracking in production, it seems to work well.

See [How change tracking works in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377647/how-change-tracking-works-in-entity-framework) for a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Would you advise me to keep that line, or remove it? If you advise keeping, then why?

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason for the explicit notification, I would remove it.